# Are angels visible at the speed of light?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, science, malaikah, theology

I was wondering if the angels are made of light, could we see them if we traveled at the speed of light?

Comment: I'm sorry for the tag the site told me I couldn't make a tag from a mobile phone

Comment: If you jump into a fire and start burning, are you going to see the devils?

Comment: Hello Atata there is no connection with what your saying and the laws of physics but may Alla reword you for trying to help me

Comment: Angels are not made of physical light! The concept of light should be understood as a metaphor for knowledge, perfection and transcendence.

Comment: Can you give me evadence on your clams that angels are not made out of physical light please, thank you infatuated

Comment: You're welcome! Have a look at [the site tour](http://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how users acknowledge desirable answers and questions in the site. You can (and normally should) also notify the users when responding to them in comments by typing @username in your reply comment.

Answer (score 1):

All religions including Islam agree that angels in essence are not corporeal beings otherwise not only the Prophets but anyone nearby could normally see them when they appeared to the Prophets to communicate Divine messages or when they descend upon believers to support them without appearing to them in a visible physical form (as they did to believers in the Battle of Badr, as well as to the disciples of Jesus). Nonetheless religious scriptures do not rule out that angels *can* appear in a visible corporeal form either to Prophets or commons (as in the case of those who appeared to Abraham and people of Lut), but this is evident by both scriptures and our own understanding that angels are normally incorporeal and invisible to us except, as scriptures show, when they are ordered to appear in a physical form to Prophets or ordinary people to fulfill special Divine decrees.

Obviously or not, the reason for Angels' ability to be both visible and invisible, and their ability to assume and take off physical forms is that in their capacity as executors of Divine orders in the natural world, they occupy an intermediary plane between the Divine realm and the natural realm hence assuming some of the characteristics of both.

So considering the incorporeal nature of angels, "light" that is said to constitute their existence can not be a physical being. But even assuming that light that make's up angels is physical light, there is no reason for the connection perceived between the ability to travel at the speed of a being's "building blocks" and the ability to see that being!

Answer (score -2):

What is the relation between to be created from something and the speed of it ?!!
if you traveled by the speed of sound you will not see the sound of music ... wait a second , oh yes you will see it :D . ok go for the speed of light and tell us what you will see .

Comment: hello Atata, what you said is an unfair comparison if you studied physics befor you would know that if you traveled at the speed of light it would not move ahead of you for example if me and you are running at the same speed I would be able to see you better than when you running off.

Comment: We can see sound waves because we traveled at the speed of sound http://youtu.be/gWGLAAYdbbc this may educate you on some physics brother

Comment: A friendly word of advice Ahmed  I apreshate what you replied but pleas do your reasherch and may Alla reword for trying to help me my brother

Comment: I strongly recommend you to read http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer and take the http://islam.stackexchange.com/tour to learn more about this site!